# how to route parameters latitude and longitude from google autocomplete place angular 2?

Tags: path, angular2-routing

I'm using angular 2 and in this part (home page) I have a google autocomplete place input that if you click it goes another page(map) and it shows the map with that latitude and longitude user clicked previous page. However the point is I want in the URL, lat and long will be shown.It's complicated for me and don't know what to do,also I have read https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#parameterized-route but didn't understand.

app-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent }  from './home/home.component';
import { MapComponent }  from './search/map.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'home',     component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'map/'+this.latitude+','+this.longitude,     component: 
  MapComponent },
  ];

@NgModule({
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

in the path I wrote like this but don't know is correct or not.

home.html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 container search-location">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="search" placeholder="select place" 
 autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" 
 class="form-control"
       #search [formControl]="searchControl">
 </div>
 </div>
```

home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgModule, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild } from 
'@angular/core';
 import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from 
"@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
declare let google: any;
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
selector: 'home-search',
templateUrl: './home-search.html',
styles: [`
 agm-map {
  height: 300px;
 }
`],
})
export class HomeSearchComponent implements OnInit {
 public google:any;
 public latitude: number;
 public longitude: number;
 public searchControl: FormControl;
 public zoom: number;

 @ViewChild("search")
 public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

constructor(
private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
private ngZone: NgZone,
private router:Router,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
let options = {
  types: ["address"],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "ir"}
};
//set google maps defaults
this.zoom = 4;
this.latitude = 39.8282;
this.longitude = -98.5795;

//create search FormControl
this.searchControl = new FormControl();

//set current position
this.setCurrentPosition();

//load Places Autocomplete
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  let autocomplete = new 
google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, 
{options});
  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      //get the place result
      let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

      //verify result
      if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
        return;
      }

      //set latitude, longitude and zoom
      this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
      this.zoom = 12;

      this.router.navigate(['/map/'+this.latitude+','+this.longitude]);
    });
  });
});
}

 private setCurrentPosition() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    this.zoom = 12;
  });
 }
 }
 }
```

map.html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 container search-location">
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="true" 
[zoom]="zoom">
<agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
</div>
```

map.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgModule, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild } from 
'@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from 
"@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
declare let google: any;

@Component({
selector: 'map',
templateUrl: './map.html',
styles: [`
agm-map {
  height: 300px;
}
```

`],
    })
    export class MapComponent implements OnInit{

```
private google:any;
private latitude: number;
private longitude: number;
private searchControl: FormControl;
private zoom: number;


ngOnInit(){

}
}
```

It relates to parameters but I don't know how to write the code.
Could you please help me,I'm confused.
Thank you.